# Why does this script run differently on different accounts?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Okay, so I've written a reprofile script for copying/pasting local files.
The file works fine, but it doesn't always give the first 'CHOICE' command.

It seems to be happening when the C:\temp\logs folder doesn't exist. If that folder doesn't exist it will jump to :COPYFILES. If it's there it works fine. Could anyone revise my code? Maybe there's something wrong with that initial 'IF NOT EXIST' statement that I can't see...
Thoughts?

```bat
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%i in ('qwinsta /server:%COMPUTERNAME% ^| findstr "console"') do (set loggedInUser=%%j)

setlocal

echo Logged In User: %loggedInUser%
REM REMOVED AS UNRELATED [NOT MINIMAL] CODE

:INTRO
REM REMOVED AS UNRELATED [NOT MINIMAL] CODE
echo Logged In User: %loggedInUser%
REM REMOVED AS UNRELATED [NOT MINIMAL] CODE

:CHECKLOGS
IF NOT EXIST "C:\temp\logs\" (
    mkdir "C:\temp\logs\"
    echo.>"C:\temp\logs\appsense_BACKUP_robo.txt" 
) ELSE (
    echo.>"C:\temp\logs\appsense_BACKUP_robo.txt" 

    :STARTPROMPT
    CHOICE /C 12 /N /M "Are you wanting to: Copy Files [1] OR Paste Files [2]?"
    IF ERRORLEVEL 2 goto PASTEFILES
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto CHECKEXIST
)

:CHECKEXIST
IF EXIST "C:\temp\appsensebackup\%loggedInUser%" (
    echo APPSENSE BACKUP FOLDER FOR %loggedInUser% ALREADY EXISTS.

    CHOICE /C 12 /N /M "Would you like to: Delete Previous Backup [1] OR Cancel [2]?"
    IF ERRORLEVEL 2 goto USERCANCEL
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto REMDIR
) ELSE (
    GOTO :COPYFILES
)

:REMDIR
REM REMOVED AS UNRELATED [NOT MINIMAL] CODE
GOTO :COPYFILES 

:COPYFILES
REM REMOVED AS UNRELATED [NOT MINIMAL] CODE
EXIT

:PASTEFILES
REM REMOVED AS UNRELATED [NOT MINIMAL] CODE
EXIT

:USERCANCEL
REM REMOVED AS UNRELATED [NOT MINIMAL] CODE

endlocal
```

Comment: I would start by asking, how is this script is being run? _(It seems a rather convoluted method of returning a single 'logged in' users account name on `%ComputerName%`_).

Comment: I was looking at the script t clean it up, you are trying to backup the user on console, but, is this being doe by another user?  If not then the part with QWinsta is not needed, you can user %USERPROFILE% and %USERNAME% to get the profile directories etc

Comment: GlenRitchie, I have removed the unrelated and non minimal code from your question, _(please see [mcve])_. This forum is not somewhere you post your code expecting others to improve it for you, it is only for requesting help with a specific replicable issue.

Comment: Thanks Compo and Ben. So previously this was being ran as administrator, so needed to pull the logged in username. This is not longer the case, so you're right. I've now updated to use %username% and %userprofile% to clean up some code.

Comment: @GlenRitchie, if you create a [tag:batch-file] with only the following content, `@Echo %UserName%&Pause` and run it 'As administrator' it should still output your account name, not Administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that the reason you believe the code you posted "doesn't work" is that you probably didn't intend to wall up the Start Prompt under that choice the way you did.

Note: In general you should avoid using GOTO and instead use CALL.

This picture represents the logical flow of your code, I have highlighted the path I believe your code is taking in Orange, and I have highlighted the issue in Red.

[image]

As highlighted in Red, you only include the chose part in the case where the Directory already exists.

Here is the specific block of code at issue:

```
:CHECKLOGS
IF NOT EXIST "C:\temp\logs\" (
mkdir "C:\temp\logs\"
echo.>"C:\temp\logs\appsense_BACKUP_robo.txt" 
) ELSE (
echo.>"C:\temp\logs\appsense_BACKUP_robo.txt" 


:STARTPROMPT
CHOICE /C 12 /N /M "Are you wanting to: Copy Files [1] OR Paste Files [2]?"
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 goto PASTEFILES
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto CHECKEXIST
)
```

You probably intended to write this as:

```
:CHECKLOGS
IF NOT EXIST "C:\temp\logs\" (
mkdir "C:\temp\logs\"
echo.>"C:\temp\logs\appsense_BACKUP_robo.txt" 
) ELSE (
echo.>"C:\temp\logs\appsense_BACKUP_robo.txt" 
)

:STARTPROMPT
CHOICE /C 12 /N /M "Are you wanting to: Copy Files [1] OR Paste Files [2]?"
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 goto PASTEFILES
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto CHECKEXIST
```

I believe simply using the above will fix your code to the way you expect it.

That said the whole script could be tightened up immensely if you would like to follow some good practices (and quite a bit further still in fact).

Answer (score 0):

Your first prompt is inside the ELSE clause of your IF statement.
I personally just attempt to make the directory and let it fail instead of bothering to check if it exists.
Like this:

```
...
:CHECKLOGS
md "C:\temp\logs\" >nul 2>nul
echo.>"C:\temp\logs\appsense_BACKUP_robo.txt"
:STARTPROMPT
CHOICE /C 12 /N /M "Are you wanting to: Copy Files [1] OR Paste Files [2]?"
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 goto PASTEFILES
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto CHECKEXIST


:CHECKEXIST
color 0C
...
```

If you want to keep it the way you have it:

```
...
:CHECKLOGS
IF NOT EXIST "C:\temp\logs\" md "C:\temp\logs\"
echo.>"C:\temp\logs\appsense_BACKUP_robo.txt" 

:STARTPROMPT
CHOICE /C 12 /N /M "Are you wanting to: Copy Files [1] OR Paste Files [2]?"
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 goto PASTEFILES
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto CHECKEXIST


:CHECKEXIST
color 0C
...
```

I see no reason for that first IF statement to have an ELSE clause.